# How can I use tiling in a game with python and pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, tiling

I'm creating a 2D platformer type shooting game using python and pygame, and I'm trying to add in tiling mechanics so If I created a platform 100 pixels long and the tile image was only 70 pixels long, it would draw one tile and half of another, so I created a simple prototype, but I can't get it to draw the sprite. Here's my code for it:

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

class Rec(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, x, y, w, height):

        super().__init__()

        self.b = 0
        self.image = pygame.image.load("grass.png").convert()
        if w <= 70:
            self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (w, height))
        elif w > 70:
            self.image = pygame.Surface([w, height])
            while self.b < w:
                self.image.blit(pygame.image.load("grass.png").convert(), (x + self.b, y))
                self.b += 70

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

pygame.init()

size = (700, 500)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

rec = Rec(100, 200, 140, 70)
all_sprites_list.add(rec)

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Platformers always use use full tile - so make  platform 70px or create tile 50px (2*50=100) or create two tiles 70px + 30px

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I know how to draw full and half tiles and everything, I just can't get it to actually draw it onto the screen. When I run it the platform is just black.

Comment: so you gave not enough information - you didn't said you have black screen :) And nobody will run code to see your real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
self.image.blit(pygame.image.load("grass.png").convert(), (x + self.b, y))
```

should be

```
self.image.blit(pygame.image.load("grass.png").convert(), (self.b, 0))
```

since the position you pass to the `blit` function are relative to the `Surface` you blit on; but `x` and `y` are screen coordinates.

So in your example you blit the grass image with a position of `x + self.b = 100`, `y = 200` on a `Surface` which has a size of `(140, 70)`, while you should blit the it at `(0, 0)`.